# I'm trying to create a spirograph program which allows the user to input the angle used

Tags: python

Using the code below I get the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\turtleTest2.py", line 4, in <module>
    x = input(int("Choose a number for the spirograph to use "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Choose a number for the spirograph to use '
```

---

```
#TURTLES!!!2
import turtle

x = input(int("Choose a number for the spirograph to use "))

def drawASquare(whichTurtle):
    for loopCounter in range(4):
        whichTurtle.forward(200)
        whichTurtle.right(x)

window = turtle.Screen()
timmy = turtle.Turtle()
timmy.speed(0)



colorCounter = 1

while True:
    drawASquare(timmy)
    timmy.left(2)
    if colorCounter == 1:
    timmy.color('blue')
    elif colorCounter == 2:
        timmy.color('red')
    elif colorCounter == 3:
        timmy.color('yellow')
    elif colorCounter == 4:
        timmy.color('green')
        colorCounter = 0
    colorCounter += 1
```

I am doing this for a school side-project to learn more about Python programming. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your indentation is messed up for python standards.

Comment: That is usually a problem caused by copy/paste from the idle window to SO, not a code issue experience by OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got the calls to the built-ins backwards.  It should be like this:

```
x = int(input("Choose a number for the spirograph to use "))
```

The above code gets the input and then converts it to an integer.  Your original code was trying to make this into an integer:

```
"Choose a number for the spirograph to use "
```

which will never work.